# RangeFormat.columnWidth and RangeFormat.autofitColumns() for Officejs API doesn't work

Tags: office-addins, office-js, excel-2016

I'm having an issue with columnWidth not actually setting and showing in Excel 2016.  Below is where my Excel.run function is:

```
        _columns = columns;
        var headers = [];
        var numCols = _columns.length;
        var letter = columnToLetter(numCols); //for perspective, this becomes "P"
        for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            var header = [];
            header.push(_columns[i].header);
            headers.push(header); //basically an array of arrays, where each entry is ["some string"]
        }

        var ranges = [];
        Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync(['Sheet1!A', letter].join(':'), 'table', { id: 'table' });

        Excel.run(function (context) {

            var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
            for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {


                var range = sheet.getCell(0, i);
                range.load(['values', 'text', 'format/columnWidth']);
                ranges.push(range);

            }

            return context.sync().then(function () {

                for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
                    ranges[i].values = [headers[i]]; //now each range, which is essentially one cell, has one value in values. values = [["some string"]]
                    headerFormatFn(ranges[i]);
                    context.sync();
                }



            })
            .catch(function (err) { console.error(err); })
        });
```

and the actual formatting happens in the headerFormatFn(ranges[i]):

```
    function headerFormatFn(cell) {


        cell.format.font.bold = true;
        cell.format.borders.getItem(1).style = 'Continuous';
        cell.format.columnWidth = 80;

    }
```

I've checked support for ExcelApi in my Excel 2016 and i know autofitColumns() isn't supported so I gather that's why the function doesn't work.  I'll need to update Excel 2016 for that.  However, columnWidth is a property that is supported in ExcelApi 1.1 and so it is supported in my version of Excel 2016.

It's odd because `format.font.bold` and `format.borders` works just fine.  It appears that just setting the columnWidth is not working.  See below for a view of the resulting worksheet:

[Resulting Excel 2016 Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieoU0.png)

I can't tell if this has something to do with `context`, or if maybe we're setting up our Excel Add-in wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if any more information is needed let me know.

**-------UPDATE 1-------**

In response to answer by @Michael, I made these changes:

I changed my Excel.run to:

```
        Excel.run(function (context) {

            var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
            for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {


                var range = sheet.getCell(0, i);
                range.load(['values', 'text', 'format/*']);
                ranges.push(range);

            }
            for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {

                ranges[i].values = [headers[i]];
                headerFormatFn(ranges[i]);
            }
            return context.sync()
            .catch(function (err) { console.error(err); })
        });
```

and i'm using `border.getItemAt(0).style  = 'Continuous'` now:

```
        try {
            console.log("1");
            cell.format.font.bold = true;
            console.log("2");
            cell.format.borders.getItemAt(0).style = 'Continuous';
            console.log("3");
            cell.format.columnWidth = 80;
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
```

The logs of 1, 2, and 3 show that the loop completes then gives an `OfficeExtensionError` of `InvalidArgument` after the loop on the context.sync() call.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I think it's the `cell.format.borders.getItem(1).style` line that is causing the issue.  I don't think you can do a `getItem(1)`, as `1` is not a valid key.  You instead want something like `InsideHorizontal`, as in:

```
range.format.borders.getItem('InsideHorizontal').style = 'Continuous';
```

When something in a batch fails, no further queued-up changes get executed, which is why the columnWidth line is not triggering.

That being said, I think the real issue with the code is that you're silently swallowing errors and also "breaking the promise chain".  The offending code is:

```
            for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
                ...
                context.sync();
            }
```

Two problems with this:

1. You are doing a `context.sync()` in each for loop.  You are almost certainly not intending to do this (and this will fail after you have ~50 columns, as Excel can only handle X many in-parallel requests).  What you want is to do the `sync` **only once**, beneath the `for` loop.
2. You are not doing a "return" of `context.sync()`.  This means that for all intents and purposes, the Excel.run no longer awaits on context.sync, but instead finishes what it's doing and moves on.  The `context.sync()` at that point becomes a separate workstream that is spawned off, but is not tracked by the parent.  Which means that the `catch` on the parent isn't able to catch any issues that arise during that child `sync`.

I am in the process of creating a site/book to take some of the mystery out of Office.js and its internal workings.  I can post here when I have the topic ready to view (I have one on "not breaking the promise chain" in particular).

Comment: I updated my question with changes suggested in your answer and still receive issues.  See **UPDATE 1**.  I now receive different errors, but still columns do not resize.

Comment: Also relevant is that the error i'm getting now is one I was receiving already, and that's why I added the context.sync() inside the loop because it populated all my cells that way.  This code is in no way finalized, I was simply trying to find a way to get the columns to appear and resize.

Comment: @JoshuaLandi, something about your updated code is wrong, in that `range.load(['values', 'text', 'format/*']);` is loaded but not used.  Is there a sync you want somewhere in the middle of this all?

Comment: @JoshuaLandi, I highly recommend that you inspect the `debugInfo` property of the error object and see what location it points to.  That can be of great help to diagnose which call is causing the error.

Comment: You might also be having separate issues with `Office.context.document.bindings.addFromNamedItemAsync`, as you're calling it but then letting it run as is, independently of your other code block (is that intended?)

Comment: So i'm basically working with someone else's code who was seemingly more familiar with OfficeJS and so I left some code along and accepted it as correct.  But now that you pointed it out I changed how I was doing my formatting by using the Bindings and callbacks.  However that lead into another issue that i've posted separately since it's a new issue.

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40285931/tablebinding-setdataasync-cellformat-parameter-causes-call-to-end-without-error)